# Whatspp button is not working on browsers?

Tags: whatsapi

I'm using a whatsapp button on my website, but when I click on it, the message to send appears, and when I click on it, the html appears.

I've seen in some forums that it's a bug in the whatsapp API, is someone else going through it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is broken due to empty `content-type` response header, browser expects something like `text/html` value to start rendering the response.

[Official Whats Up doc](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030) suggests to use

```
https://wa.me/1234567
```

link format for send message links, where 1234567 is tel number.

You can update generated code to use this format.